How to simplify this intersect query?
SELECT * from M
left JOIN K on M.id = k.id
left JOIN W on K.str = W.str where str = N'أخبار'
 
INTERSECT
 
SELECT * from M
left JOIN K on m.id = k.id
left JOIN W on K.str = W.str where str = N'فلسطين'

How else to get all rows in M that have a relationship to both أخبار AND فلسطين in W?

Do you really need in ALL columns values?


How else to get all rows in M that have a relationship to both أخبار AND فلسطين in W?

SELECT * from M WHERE
EXISTS (select * from K left join W on K.str = W.str
         where K.ID=M.ID and str = N'أخبار')
and 
EXISTS  (select * from K left join W on K.str = W.str
         where K.ID=M.ID and str = N'فلسطين')

My point is - I like EXISTS - it's easy to understand how it works for average developer so the code is easier to maintain.
EDIT.

The OP's query returns all columns from all 3 tables, unlike your query

Feel free to perform left join for selected rows
SELECT * from M
left join K on K.ID=M.ID
left join W on K.str = W.str
WHERE
EXISTS (select * from K left join W on K.str = W.str
         where K.ID=M.ID and str = N'أخبار')
and 
EXISTS  (select * from K left join W on K.str = W.str
         where K.ID=M.ID and str = N'فلسطين')


If your purpose is to get a better performance, you could try this:
SELECT * FROM M JOIN (  
    SELECT K.id FROM K JOIN W ON K.str = W.str
    WHERE W.str IN ( N'أخبار', N'فلسطين')
    GROUP BY K.id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT W.str) > 1
    ) AS KW ON (M.id = KW.id)

The inner select will get the K.id's associated with two different strings, and the outer one will retrieve records in M associated to those id's.
Since you are testing for non-null values in W, you can use inner JOINS instead of left joins.

The OP's query returns all columns from all 3 tables, unlike your query.
